# Developing mobile apps using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I read through all existing posts on the same topic, but I still have a little bit more specific question.

I'm about to start developing a mobile application for several mobile platforms (iPhone, Android, Blackbery...). It is a simple geo-locating service using google maps, talking to various REST services, retriving and displaying that data, etc.

I wonder if Titanium is good enough to meet these requirements? Does it port well on all platforms and works properly? Are there any issues or disadvantages I should know about before starting with Titanium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already worked with titanium (for android and ios) using a rest service which worked fine. the kitchen sink, a great heap of examples for titanium, comprised a [geolocation example](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/geolocation.js), so i guess it will work.